# wso2 developer studio dss mongo data source type removed

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio

I just downloaded WSO2 Developer Studio for Mac 64bit. I tried setting up a MongoDB data source. However, the MongoDB option no longer exists. Has WSO2 discontinued MongoDB support in DSS or is there some way to re-enable it?

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 didn't discontinue MongoDB support in DSS 3.5.1. You can add Mongo DB data source in the data service. It's available in the management console as well.

Thanks,
Madhawa

Comment: "You can add Mongo DB data source in the data service." How is this done? The New Data Source wizard for adding a data service does not include MongoDB as an option as it used to.